# Python Lambda no such file or directory found run time issue

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function that is returning back an error that no such file or directory has been found.

To be clear the image below shows the file structure exists in my lambda and it is clear that the directory that I am looking for does exist.

[My current file structure in the lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHO7I.png)

Error Message that I am receiving:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    os.chdir("config")
```

Below is the lambda_handler:

```
import os
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
    print(event)
    os.chdir("config")
    loginInfo = json.load(open('secrets.json'))
    return loginInfo
```

The reason why I am changing the directory to config is so that I can access my secrets.json file.

Please let me know if this is sufficient detail to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running as a Lambda is not the same as running on your dev machine.
If you want to read config - you have several options:

1. Env variables
2. Uplaod your config file to s3 and read it from there
3. Use AWS parameter store and read the config from there,

Comment: 4. Point to a config value in a database table (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run it locally you could check `aws sam cli`.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli

It requires you to define a default cloudformation `template.yml` with setup of your lambda function.

In the end just execute

`sam local invoke  -e lambda-event.json`

Answer (score 0):

I am ignoring the details posted here - I am sure they are valuable - and going to go on a tangent and  mention that since you are handling secrets, it is worth investing in a future proof secrets management policy.

https://dev.to/dvddpl/where-do-you-keep-credentials-for-your-lambda-functions-5dno

[Using AWS Secrets Manager with Python (Lambda Console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000751/using-aws-secrets-manager-with-python-lambda-console)